# can i show/hide elements depending on the selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what should happen:
If the value 'NL' is selected the fields 'place' and 'street' are not necessary. It should be hidden. When the value 'BE' is selected, it should show the 'place' and 'street' fields/rows (with class for-be). On default it should be hidden since 'NL' is selected by default.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Country: </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="country" id="Select">
            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Zipcode: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="zipcode" maxlength="6"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="for-be">
    <td><label>Place: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="place" maxlength="60"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="for-be">
    <td><label>Street: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="street" maxlength="60"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Number: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="number" maxlength="5"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the code in jQuery i have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('#Select');

    if(select.val() == 'NL'){
        $('.for-be').hide();
    }

    select.change(function(){

        if(select.val() == 'NL'){
            $('.for-be').hide();
        } else if(select.val() == 'BE'){
            $('.for-be').show();
        }
    });
});
```

<strike>It doesn't work this way.</strike>
Edit: It works this way (added the missing ');')

Comment: Syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` i.e. closing parenthesis missing `)` foe event handler. Rest of code works  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you are right @Satpal

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGzEKJ

```
select.change(function(){
  var selectedV = $('option:selected',this).attr('value');
  if(selectedV == 'BE'){
    $('.for-be').hide();
  }else {
    $('.for-be').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to implement simple logic.

HTML :

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><label>Country: </label></td><td><select name="country" id="Select"><option value="NL">Netherlands</option><option value="BE">Belgium</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Zipcode: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="zipcode" maxlength="6"></td></tr>
<tr class="BE all_value"><td><label>Place: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="place" maxlength="60"></td></tr>
<tr class="BE all_value"><td><label>Street: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="street" maxlength="60"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Number: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="number" maxlength="5"></td></tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('#Select');

    select.change(function(){
     $(".all_value").hide();
     $("."+select.val()).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: append same class as value so you don't need to write if else. 
in feature you are add 100 country then jquery code will work for all.

Just pass class name which country need that fields !

Answer (score 0):

Try select.on(). Here's a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/57gok7c9/

```
select.on('change',function(){

    if(select.val() == 'NL'){
        $('.for-be').hide();
    } else if(select.val() == 'BE'){
        $('.for-be').show();
    }
});
```

EDIT - As satpal pointed out, there's a simple syntax error in your code.

Comment: on is needed only if the elements are not there at DOM ready. This is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$('#Select').change(function () {

var textVal= $(this).val();

if (textVal== 'NE') {
     $('.for-be').hide();
}
else if(textVal=='BE') {
     $('.for-be').show();
}
});
```